# Copying contents of a specific folder in master branch and put it in a new branch

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I am new to github and I am trying to put the contents of a folder in the master branch to a new branch. I have a git repository with the following contents (master branch)

```
> Folder 
> Node Practice
     > Sub Folder 1
     > Sub Folder 2
     > Web server
> Another folder
> Readme
```

Now,I wanna a create a new branch (named heroku), where I just wanna copy all the contents of the Web server Folder and put it in this new branch. How can I achieve that?

Comment: A branch doesn't seem like the right tool for the job. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Do you want this branch to be in the same repository, and do you want this new branch to be related to `master`?

Comment: There are several solutions, but it really depends what your expectations are for how this new branch will behave as the code on `master` (or other branches) continues to evolve.  You might be better off to make a new repository for the `Web server` folder, and replace the original repo's copy of the `Web server` folder with a submodule reference.

Comment: @JBNizet I don't wanna create a new repository. This web sever folder is basically a web application and i wanna deploy it on heroku. So I am creating a branch so that I can link this branch to heroku instead of creating a new repository. Since this is my first deployment and I won't be using it anymore, I don't want to create a new repo.

Comment: When you say "I won't be using it anymore"... what does that mean?  If you're saying it's a one-off solution, then why bother with some complicated git procedure?  Just copy the files you need and be done with it.  If you hadn't said that, I'd assume this was an ongoing part of your build procedure - and in that case, see my previous comment, because a branch with a subdirectory of another branch will be *difficult* to keep in sync as changes continue to occur.